# why there is difference between original and compiled code

Tags: java, decompiling

Here i am tried to compile the java file and i used java decompiler to check the compiled code.why char is converted int and some of the variable names also changed?

### ORIGINAL JAVA FILE

```
class CharacterTest{
public static void main(String[] args){

    char t=140; 
    char f='t';
    char p='t';
    System.out.print(t);

}
}
```

### COMPILED CODE

```
import java.io.PrintStream;

class CharacterTest
{
public static void main(String[] paramArrayOfString)
{
char c = '';
int i = 116;
int j = 116;
System.out.print(c);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It completely depends on decompiler implementation details. Decompiler doesn't know names and types of your local variables, so it has to use some heuristics to reconstruct it from the bytecode.

Your bytecode looks as follows:

```
   0:   sipush  140   
   3:   istore_1      
   4:   bipush  116   
   6:   istore_2      
   7:   bipush  116   
   9:   istore_3
```

As you can see `140` is treated as a constant of type `short`, whereas `116` is treated as a constant of type `byte` (it's caused by the fact that `116` fits into a signed byte, but `140` doesn't).

Now decompiler tries to guess what could it mean in the source code. It looks like decompiler treats difference in constant types as difference in the types of local variables (also it can use the signature of `print()` choosen by compiler as a hint to determine the type of `t`), and variable names are generated depending on types (`c` for `char`, `i` and `j` for `int`).

**See also:**

- [The Java Virtual Machine Instruction Set](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Instructions.doc.html)

Comment: ok..leave about change of variable in this case but can you give some more explanation about change of char into int?

Comment: @setheesh: There is no change. Decopiler doesn't know types of local variables and tries to guess it from the bytecode.

Answer (score 2):

JVM and bytecode do not distinguish between char and int per se. This is only on the semantic/language level.

And second local variable names are not contained in the class file. Thus the decompiler has to invent his own names.

Answer (score 0):

A char is really an Integer type.

The char type (a character) contains a single, 16-bit Unicode character, that are actually represented by unsigned 16-bit integers.

*(source: SCJP by Kathy Sierra)*

About the naming change, I don't know for sure. But I guess it's an issue of your decompiler. Have you tried different decompilers and saw the variable names that everyone produced?

Comment: char why char t=140; didn't change to int

Answer (score 0):

As said, local variables for the VM can only have the types (or more exactly, can be accessed with commands for) `int`, `long`, `float`, `double` and *reference* - so all integer types (apart from long) are treated as `int` internally.

The first variable remains `char` since this is the argument type of the `println()` method called here, so the compiler has some way to guess it, while the other two variables are not used anymore, so they stay `int` here.